# Git push changing ownership of files causing 500 server error

Tags: linux, git, terminal

Problems with git push causing 500 server errors. Appears to be a file permission problem according to the server errors. the ownership of the files change each time I do a git push from my local machine.

In order to get things working again, I have to go into the public_html folder and `chown potter.potter * -R`

could anybody help me here? I have shown below how I have set things up...

I have set up a repository called potter.git on the development server of my website within /home/username/gitrepos

```
ssh root@potter.com

git config --global user.email "harry@potter.com"  
git config --global user.name "harry"
```

within /home/potter/gitrepos

```
mkdir potter.git  
cd potter.git  
git init --bare
```

setup hooks to allow deployment

```
cd hooks  
pico post-receive
```

Entered the following into post-receive hook to allow deployment

```
#!/bin/bash
#
docroot="/home/potter/public_html"
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`

if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
git --work-tree=$docroot checkout -f $branch
fi

done
```

made post-receive executable

```
chmod 755 post-receive
```

set working directories in .bash-profile

```
# GIT  
export GIT_DIR=/home/potter/potter.git  
export GIT_WORK_TREE=~/public_html
```

Now on my local machine, I set up the remote connection as follows:

```
git remote add website ssh://root@potter.com/home/potter/potter.git
```

and to push, i do the following:

```
git push website master
```

Answer (score 0):

The file owner is the one who does the checkout, so that would be the user you connect to. And since you connect to root, all files are owned by root.

First I would not use root as the git user. I would create a new user specifically for that task.

Second, I would disable root login via ssh. Use `su` or `sudo` if you want to play god.

Third, if you want to run a script as a different user (for example a checkout script), you could use an ssh connection to the correct user at localhost (`potter@localhost`) and use public key authentication to log in without a password. You can specify a command that ssh should execute immediately after login. So somewhere in your homedir you could create a script that changes to the correct directory and runs git checkout.

Comment: thanks for advice. I have create a new user 'git' and have chown the gitrepos folder to 'git' instead of root. Now... Aren't I going to have another 500 server error when I git push using 'git@potter.....'?

Comment: You should not have any more internal server errors (500) due to incorrect permissions when you follow my third advise.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same when using cPanel on Centos if the file ownerships are not set correctly then apache throws a 500 error. May be nothing wrong with the code or the file permission settings.

You can create a hook, like I have.

After running any pull run this file to quickly reset any file ownerships. 
 When you run it make sure your in the directory you wish to update.

```
 #!/bin/bash
    for file in `ls -a | grep -v '^\.'`
    do
            if [[ -d $file ]]
            then
                    fowner=`ls -ld $file | awk '{print $3}'`
                    fgroup=`ls -ld $file | awk '{print $4}'`
                    chown -R $fowner:$fgroup $file
            fi
    done
```